# JavaScript - Printing Out Event Handlers on Divs Outputted Using Arrays and a For Loop

Tags: html, arrays, dynamic, for-loop, event-handling

I've been trying to figure this out for the last couple of days, but I just can't seem to get it right.  The idea is that when someone fills out a form clicks a button named calc, it will gather the user input, store it in a variable, and output it into an array.  Then, using a for loop, the messages stored in the array will populate below the form.  I want each instance of the message, however, to have an event handle associated with it.  Getting the event handler to work for all of the outputted messages just won't work.  Thanks for the help! :)

http://jsbin.com/azozad/13/edit